# Does it make sense - is it recomended - to over work my whole mysql models changing ids from varchar UTF8 to ascii char?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am developing in RAILS and was using SQLITE (not a sqlite question) when I started.

Now some months later and after running into COLLATE problems in my - now MySQL databases, I removed my designer cap and put on my database administrator cap ...

I realized that - for some reason I am not sure about, I can't remember - all tables are `charset 'utf8' collate 'utf8_unicode_ci'`, what in principle is ok, since more ore less all tables have 'multi lingual texts'

But I also moved from rails default *auto increment integer* IDs to UUID as primary key. And this are - somehow thanks to RAILS - varchar(36)

(after first success with BIN format for UUID I decided to step back to literal UUIDs because of tool problems)

But this ids (PK, FK) are also UTF8 and collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' and - as mentioned varchar(36)

So now I think about reworking the whole database schema to  all ids (PF anf FK) to `char(36) charset 'ascii' collate 'ascii'`

But I am afraid, what Rails does with this and what it means for further migrations.

So - again - shall I change 'my winning team' (it works fine) for better performance, for beauty?

The point is, that I do not have millions of records, I am not sure what it means for MySql to have a `varchar(36) utf8` instead of an `ascii char(36)` - sure later would be faster and takes less space, but is it worth it?

Comment: Changing the collation seems like a total waste of time. But then again I prefer postgres that actually has a native UUID column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there was a good reason to use UUID vs Integers, but if you are not reverting to Integers you shouldn't worry, not worth it, your app still can run fine with millions of records.

*"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*